# What SCM does support symlinks under Windows and Linux?

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, symlink

I found out that [subversion doesn't support symlinks under Windows](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3570).

I'm wondering if somebody knows a SCM tool that is able to work with symlinks under both Windows and Linux?

SCM tools currently missing symlink support under Windows:

- Clear Case
- Subversion
- Mercurial
- Perforce

Comment: Supporting symlinks on Windows is a feat in itself. It's possible, but not documented well sadly. It's also only possible on NTFS formatted drives, for whatever that's worth. Most Windows systems are running on NTFS anyway these days. For more information, have a look here: http://elsdoerfer.name/=ntfslink

Comment: Note that windows does support "NTFS junction points" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) for directories.

Comment: I think that Microsoft documented pretty well how symbolic links are working and how to use them here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365680(VS.85).aspx

I'm wondering why I have a vote for closing the question?

Comment: "Symbolic links are available in NTFS starting with Windows Vista." Junction points are available on any NTFS system. Not sure how those symlinks work, I've not used Vista for any length of time.

Comment: I can sadly add that Clear Case doesn't support symlinks under both Windows and Linux, either.

Comment: Symlinks on Windows Vista and Windows 7 are (unless reconfigured) an administrator only feature so it would require UAC to change the links. Further Windows symlinks require the type of the target (file/directory) to be known at creation time while unix symlinks don't. (So this type is not stored in the current SCM systems)

Comment: Do you mean creating "junctions" on Windows, right? Do you all find it a strong required feature?? Because we (PlasticSCM) are just right now reviewing symlink implementation and could come up with support on Windows easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Git*** itself handles symlinks (symbolic links) natively; I mean here that Git stores information that file is symlink in repository.

I think that **[Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)** (msysGit) can represent symlinks in working directory on NTFS.  There is also **`core.symlinks`** configuration variable, that if false makes Git check out symbolic links are checked out as small plain files that contain the link text.  Git will probe and set 'core.symlinks' false if appropriate when the  repository is created (`git clone` or `git init`).

Answer (score 3):

Most SCM focus on storing normalized data (think of your SCM as a database).  This means that they store source files and build scripts instead of storing executable files derived from them.  People could store both but it leads to unnecessary duplication.

Similarly, symlinks are references to other files and represent a similar problem to data normalization.

Furthermore, pointers in general are hard to reason about.  Adding support for pointers (symlinks) in a SCM means that certain operations will need to examine where the symlinks point and act accordingly.  This makes merges harder, adding/updating symlinks is tricky because you need to figure out where it points (in repo vs. out of repo, two symlinks to same file, etc).

For these reasons, most VCS/SCM do not allow you to manage symlinks.  Most SCM do have support for user defined hooks.  Using custom hooks or other scripts to manage the symlinks is a better approach because it means the SCM doesn't have to reason about them (it's ignorant to them), and you are side-stepping the issue of data normalization that they create.

So, in conclusion, you're best off writing scripts that manages your symlinks and then calling those at the appropriate times (clone/checkout, update/commit, etc).